# File.Copy method

Tags: c#, .net

Is it posiible that the following code doesn't throw any exception and doesn't copy files?

```
void Copy2(string from, string to)
{
    lock (_thisLock)
    {
     if (File.Exists(from))
     {
      File.Copy(from, to, true);
      return;
     }
     Logger.Write("File does not exists");
    }
}
```

Customer says that the application doesn't crash and doesn't copy any file, and doesn't write log. 
Logger's type is `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger`.

Comment: If the "from" file doesn't exist it's not going to do anything, but I'm assuming that's not your problem...

Comment: Can you double-check the logger configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, if the file doesn't exist - `(!File.Exists)` - then the `File.Copy` call won't get reached.

`Logger.Write` does not count as an exception.

If, as your update suggests, there is nothing in the logs, I would double check the `Logger.Write` function. Is it implemented correctly? Is there an exception being thrown and handled within that method? That would be more likely than `File.Copy` failing without throwing an exception.

Comment: Logger's type is Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger

Comment: Then you'll need to ensure you've configured the Logger correctly. Check out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/GetLoggingWithEntLib.aspx for a fairly detailed overview of using the MSEL Logging framework.

Answer (score 0):

If the file doesn't exist and no logger appenders have been configured, then the situation you describe may occur - i.e. no error, no logging

Answer (score 0):

looking at [MSDN for File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx) you can see that it throws quite a few exceptions. Make you that anything capturing the exception above the stack is handling that exception/error properly and not simply swallowing it